# Add Image to UIActivityController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiactivitycontroller

How do I add an image in the circled part of the `UIActivityController`? I don't need it included in the sharing part, I want to add it right there. I tried:

`ac.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "uLogo")`

```
let items:[Any] = [UIImage(named: "uLogo"), "What do you think of my Take on the uSTADIUM App? Sign up so you can bet with or against me!", url]
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: [])
```

Which doesn't work, so not sure how to do this

[image]

Comment: See what happens after including a URL into `activityItems`.

Comment: @ElTomato Yeah I tried that, shoulda said that in the post. The result is the same, but the image is also shared with the link

Comment: Well, it works for me if I have an array of image and url objects as `activityItems`.

Comment: @ElTomato that's weird. For me it shares the image but the image doesn't show up in that circled part in the screen shot

Comment: @ElTomato can you post your activity array?

Answer (score 1):

you can try custom `UIActivityViewController`

```
class ActivityCtrl: UIActivityViewController{
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if let cls = NSClassFromString("LPImageView"), let base = getBase(for: view, cls){
            for sub in base.subviews{
                if let img = sub as? UIImageView{
                    img.image = UIImage(named: "uLogo.png")
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func getBase(for v: UIView?, _ cls: AnyClass) -> UIView?{
           guard let vue = v else{ return nil }
           var result: UIView?
           for sub in vue.subviews{
               if sub.isKind(of: cls){
                   return sub
               }
               else {
                   result = getBase(for: sub, cls)
                   if result != nil{
                       return result
                   }
               }
           }
           return result
       }
}
```

---

usage:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.baidu.com"), let img = UIImage(named: "uLogo"){
            let items:[Any] = [img, "What do you think of my Take on the uSTADIUM App? Sign up so you can bet with or against me!", url]
            let ac = ActivityCtrl(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: [])
            present(ac, animated: true){ }
        }
```

---

The result:

[image: 999]

---

How I know `LPImageView`?

[image: 888]

Comment: weird, wasnt working for me

Comment: you can check `view hierarchy` to debug

Comment: you need notice the image src `uLogo.png`

Comment: yes I noticed the image src, does it have to be png?

Comment: no. just an ordinary image

Comment: that's what a figured, weird that it's not working

Comment: share your project on GitHub